# Extract space separated words from a sentence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have list of strings say,
`x1 = ['esk','wild man','eskimo', 'sta','(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa']`
I need to extract the x1s present in few sentences.

My sentence is  `"eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard".`
In the sentence, I need to extract first word eskimo and the seventh and eighth words wild man and they are separate words as in x1. I should not extract "stands" even though sta is present in stands.

```
def get_name(input_str):

 prod_name= []
    for row in x1:
        if (row.strip().lower()in input_str.lower().strip()) or (len([x for x in input_str.split() if "\b"+x in row])>0):
            prod_name.append(row) 
return list(set(prod_name))
```

The function
`get_name("eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard")`
returns

`[esk, eskimo,wild man,sta]`

But the expected is

`[eskimo,wild man]`

May I know what has to be changed in the code?

Comment: what is the if statement checking?

Comment: It is doing 'substring' in 'string'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach. Firstly you could split the input sentence into words and also split each of the phrases you want to check for into constituent words. Then check if each of all words of a phrase are present in the sentence.

```py
x1 = ['esk','wild man','eskimo', 'sta','(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa']
input_sentence = "eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard"
# Remove all punctuation marks from the sentence
input_sentence = input_sentence.replace('!', '').replace('.', '').replace('?', '').replace(',', '')
# Split the input sentence into its component words to check individually
input_words = input_sentence.split()

for ele in x1:
    # Split each element in x1 into words
    ele_words = ele.split()
    # Check if all words are part of the input words
    if all(ele in input_words for ele in ele_words) and ele in input_sentence:
        print(ele)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this (ele in input_words for ele in ele_words)

Comment: if each word in ele_words is present in input words (all the words in the sentence) then it will be a substring

Comment: This solution does not work for input_sentence = "is eskimo lives as a wild man?"

Comment: I would need to capture wild man in  "is eskimo lives as a wild man?". It can be ending with a "." or "?"

Comment: Then you can check if the last character is '.' or '?'. If it is, then you can remove it and then  check.

Comment: My input string can be two sentences. Say, first sentence can be a question and second a normal one.

Comment: I have edited the code now. This version should take care of all the punctuations.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use str.split(" ") to get a list of all the words in the sentence, and then do the following:

```py
s = "eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard"

l = s.split(" ")

x1 = ['esk','wild man','eskimo', 'sta','(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa']
new_x1 = [word.split(" ") for word in x1 if " " in word] + [word for word in x1 if " " not in word]

ans = []

for x in new_x1:
    if type(x) == str:
        if x in l:
            ans.append(x)
    else:
        temp = ""
        for i in x:
            temp += i + " "
        temp = temp[:-1]
        if all(sub_x in l for sub_x in x) and temp in s:
            ans.append(temp)

print(ans)
```

Comment: Will not work as " wild man" will get seperated into two words. But it has to be considered as a single entity.

Comment: Oh ok got it. This edit should have fixed that

Comment: please check so that my x1 can contain complex substring such as "(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa"

Comment: as long as there are no spaces in it, shouldn't matter. I'll take it as an entity, and checking it will be simple regardless

Comment: not working for the simple scenario itself. expected is [eskimo,wild man] but what i get from your code is ['wild', 'man']

Comment: that's a very simple manipulation. Just append  them in a list (like i did in this edit)

Comment: use isinstance(__o,str) instead of type(__o)==str

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re

x1 = ['esk','wild man','eskimo', 'sta']

my_str = "eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard"
my_list = []

for words in x1:
    if re.search(r'\b' + words + r'\b', my_str):
        my_list.append(words)
print(my_list)
```

According to the new list, because the string `(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa` generate an error with regular expressions you can use a `try` `except` block

```
for words in x1:
  try:
    if re.search(r'\b' + words + r'\b', my_str):
      my_list.append(words)
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. I am facing "error: nothing to repeat at position 3" for another set of substring. Let me edit my question.

Comment: you can use a `try` `excpet` block to avoid the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex with whitespace boundaries on the left `(?<!\S)` and right `(?!\S)` to not get partial matches,  and join all the items from the `x1` list.

Then use re.findall to get all the matches:

```
import re

x1 = ['esk','wild man','eskimo', 'sta','(+)-6-[amina(4-chlora)(1-metha-1h-imidol-5-yl)mhyl]-4-(3-chlora)-1-methyl-2(1h)-quinoa']
s = "eskimo lives as a wild man in wild jungle and he stands as a guard"
pattern = fr"(?<!\S)(?:{'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in x1)})(?!\S)"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['eskimo', 'wild man']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/V6HJFw).